# Getting involved with trading Ethereum

Tags: ether, mining, wallets

I'm looking for information on setting up **Ethereum trading account** and possibly **mining**?  I got here from link on Bitcoin Meetup email. Is there another site I should use?  I'm also **interested in Eth meetup**.

Answer (score 1):

> Remember Trading involves considerable losses if you are newbie in
>   this field.

**Keep eyes on market trends and subreddits like :**

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/
3. https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/

> Don't follow emotions but technology behind the currency.

**Anyways to kickstart trading you need two things:**

**1.** Get a ethereum address from MyEtherWallet.com , Jaxx , MEW ( remember to get the address whose private key you hold. ***A saying goes you don't hold the Assets until you hold the Private key of it***.

**2.** Get register to a trading account like [poloniex.com](http://www.poloniex.com) , [bittrex.com](http://www.bittrex.com).
I prefer bittrex over poloniex.

And after step 1 and 2 you are good to go.

**To kickstart Mining on PC you need: **

> Remember the difficulty of ethereum has gone wild since 2017 and will
>   probably keep on [hailing](https://etherscan.io/chart/difficulty). So i don't recommend mining on
>   conventional Systems.

Detail Guide: https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/

***ATH***: All Time High
***ATL***: All Time Low

Answer (score 0):

Just to address your last point about **Eth meetups**.

Ethereum meetups are mainly organised through [meetup.com](https://www.meetup.com/ethereum/). You'll be able to get notified about Blockchain Talks, Presentations, Socials, Demos and Hackathons all relating to the Ethereum community. You can also join the meetups [slack channel](https://tiny.cc/web3slack) which is a good place to ask questions.

You can actually catch up with all previous meetups via Youtube on [this link](https://www.youtube.com/user/Ursium/videos).